# Set height of div so it extends to the very end of the page, using only css?

Tags: css

Is there a way to set the height of a div using only CSS so it will fill out the reminder of the page height?

I have very limited control over the webpage (a client's custom framework), and it's not possible to change any html or use javascript.
Basically I have a textbox where I can write CSS, and that's it.

Also, I can't make fundamental changes(like introducing flex or anything like that) since it would break the page/site.
The site don't use any media queries or define viewports or anything like that. Basically they use HTML 3.2. It's an ASP.NET WebForms site where the core parts were built around 2002 - 2005.

```html
...
<body>
    ...

    <div id="rowContainer"> <!-- This is the div that needs to go all the way down to the very end 
                of the entire page. 
                (NOTE: NOT the end of the visible part of the page) -->

        <!-- child elements consist of hierarchy of divs 
              (but are row based, the content of a "row" is undefined), 
              which use a mixture of relative, absolute and fixed positioning. 
             They are dynamically generated and they are "undefined", 
              so no assumptions can be made about the child nodes -->

        <div css="row" > ... </div> <!-- These child divs might all be 
                                          absolutely positioned -->
        <div css="row" > ... </div>
        <div css="row" > <!-- row content is undefined and can change at any time --> </div>
        <div css="row" > ... </div>
    </div> <!-- There are no other visible elements after the "rowContainer" -->
</body>
```

Comment: `height:webkit-fill-available` does the work

Comment: Try defining #rowContainer {height: 100%;} or even better, find out exactly how much height it should be and define it again #rowContainer {height: 1000px(or your value);}. But as I can see, rowContainer is a ID for JavaScript, so I'm not sure that this will work. But you can try.

Comment: Use height:100vh; will work for all browsers.

Comment: I'd be careful with the use of that though if you want full browser compatibility @SaiManoj https://caniuse.com/#search=webkit-fill-available

Comment: height: 100% or height: 100vh will only set the height to what's visible on the screen. When the content does not fit on the screen, which is the normal case, it won't work.

Comment: @NoOneSpecial then set the height to 200vh

Answer (score 1):

use

```
#rowContainer{
       height:100vh;
}
```